# jQuery UI LISTVIEW not refreshing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, listview, jquery-ui-sortable

Using jQuery UI (w/ jquery 1.9.1). I have a sortable list. I'm adding dom element through a form. User clicks a button, a dialog appears. User types text into a textbox and clicks 'add page'. A new list item will append to the list. The problem is that the listview does not contain the proper CSS.

Heres a JSfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/RQKng/1/

Before you Click the red button you can click between the list items and notice the selected list item turns blue. However, any new items will not turn blue.

I tried:

```
$('#pageList ul').trigger('create').listview('refresh');
```

But I recieve an error that 'Object has not method "listview" '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: The problem is on this line :

```
$('.page').click(function() {
        $('.page').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

2: The solution is here : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/UTvwF/)

3: some explanation:

Because you have dynamic elements that are not know beforehand, you must make jQuery aware of that. from [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().

What you want is this:

```
Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant 
elements that are added to the document at a later time.
```

Solution:

```
$('.item-list').on("click","li",function() {
    $('.page').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```